# probability: are events independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have three events A,B and C and I have the following relationship:

```
P(A|B,C) = P(A|B) P(A|C)
```

Does this imply that event B and C are conditionally independent given A?

Comment: In the future, pure math questions should be asked on [mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics and not programming.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional independence of `B` and `C` given `A` is defined as:

```
P(B,C|A) = P(B|A)P(C|A)
```

If we start with `P(A|B,C)` and use Bayes' Theorem...

```
P(A|B,C) = P(B|A)P(C|A)P(A)/P(B,C)
```

but `P(C|A)P(A) = P(A|C)P(C)`

```
P(A|B,C) = P(B|A)P(A|C)P(C)/P(B,C)
```

and `P(B|A) = P(A|B)P(B)/P(A)`

```
P(A|B,C) = P(A|B)P(B)P(A|C)P(C)/P(A)P(B,C)   
P(A|B,C) = P(A|B)P(A|C)  P(B)P(C)/P(B,C)P(A)
```

So `P(A|B,C) = P(A|B)P(A|C)` does not give you conditional independence, unless `P(B)P(C)/P(B,C)P(A) = 1`.

Comment: Given this, my advice to OP is to look for a counterexample.